# Django-create filters based on each field using Q object and if elif condition

Tags: python, django, filter, qobject

I am using Q objects and I want result for all combinations of input from companyName,CompanyUrl,Subject,Class fields.
please suggest the right code for if else condition with Q object.

url.py

url(r'^filtrequest/$', views.FiltRequest.as_view())

view.py

```
class FiltRequest(APIView):
  def post(self, request, format=None):
    request.data['PubIp'] = getUserIP(request)
    returnData = ApiFiltReq.filtRequest(self, request.data, format=None)
    if returnData == "RECORD_NOT_FOUND":  # bad request
        return Response(ErrorCodes.ERROR_CODE_LIST[returnData], status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    elif returnData == "DJANGO_ENTRY_FAILED":
        return Response(ErrorCodes.ERROR_CODE_LIST[returnData], status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    else:
        return Response(returnData, status=status.HTTP_202_ACCEPTED)
```

code of ApiFiltReq.py

```
 def filtRequest(request)
    if (Q("CompanyName" in request) & Q("CompanyUrl" in request) & Q("Subject" in request) & Q("Class" in request)):
        queryset = Product.objects.filter(
            Q(CompanyName=request['CompanyName']) | Q(CompanyUrl=request['CompanyUrl']) | Q(
             Subject=request['Subject']) | Q(Class=request['Class']))

    elif (Q("CompanyName" in request)& Q("CompanyUrl" in request)& Q("Subject" in request)):
        queryset = Product.objects.filter(
            Q(CompanyName=request['CompanyName']) | Q(CompanyUrl=request['CompanyUrl']) | Q(
                Subject=request['Subject']))
    elif (Q("CompanyName" in request)& Q("CompanyUrl" in request)&Q("Class" in request)):
        queryset = Product.objects.filter(
            Q(CompanyName=request['CompanyName']) | Q(CompanyUrl=request['CompanyUrl']) | Q(Class=request['Class']))

    elif (Q("CompanyName" in request)&Q("Subject" in request)&Q("Class" in request)):
        queryset = Product.objects.filter(
            Q(CompanyName=request['CompanyName']) | Q(Subject=request['Subject']) | Q(Class=request['Class']))

    elif (Q("CompanyUrl" in request)&Q("Subject" in request)&Q("Class" in request)):
        queryset = Product.objects.filter(
            Q(CompanyUrl=request['CompanyUrl']) | Q(Subject=request['Subject']) | Q(Class=request['Class']))


    elif (Q("CompanyName" in request)& Q("CompanyUrl" in request)):
        queryset = Product.objects.filter(
            Q(CompanyName=request['CompanyName']) | Q(CompanyUrl=request['CompanyUrl']))

    elif (Q("CompanyName" in request)& Q("Subject" in request)):
        queryset = Product.objects.filter(
            Q(CompanyName=request['CompanyName']) | Q(Subject=request['Subject']))

    elif (Q("CompanyName" in request)& Q("Class" in request)):
        queryset = Product.objects.filter(
            Q(CompanyName=request['CompanyName']) | Q(Class=request['Class']))

    elif (Q("CompanyUrl" in request)& Q("Subject" in request)):
        queryset = Product.objects.filter(Q(CompanyUrl=request['CompanyUrl']) | Q(
                Subject=request['Subject']))

    elif (Q("CompanyUrl" in request)&Q("Class" in request)):
        queryset = Product.objects.filter(Q(CompanyUrl=request['CompanyUrl']) | Q(Class=request['Class']))

    elif (Q("Subject" in request)& Q("Class" in request)):
            queryset = Product.objects.filter(Q(Subject=request['Subject']) | Q(Class=request['Class']))

    elif ("CompanyName" in request):
        queryset = Product.objects.filter(CompanyName=request['CompanyName'])

    elif ("CompanyUrl" in request):
        queryset = Product.objects.filter(CompanyUrl=request['CompanyUrl'])

    elif ("Subject" in request):
        queryset = Product.objects.filter(Subject=request['Subject'])
    elif ("Class" in request):
            queryset = Product.objects.filter(Class=request['Class'])

    serializer = ProductSerializer(queryset,many=True)
    for item in serializer.data:
       sendData.append({"ProductName":item['ProductName']})
```

on running command...
curl -X POST http://localhost:8000/filtrequest/ -d '{"CompanyName":"c3","Subject":"subject2","class":"1"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json"

it gives bad request and on server the print e gives: ['CompanyUrl']
what to do to avoid it???

Comment: Can you show the error please?

Comment: I have edited with output...some requests are missing @The_Cthulhu_Kid

Comment: You have them in the wrong order =) The broadest should go last.

Comment: Try and change the order and see if you still get an error.

Comment: first three if has 2 conditions each...and fourth if has 3 condition..its in ascending order..

Comment: But if the ones with 2 are caught, the ones with 3 never will be.

Comment: oh yess..So how to edit it..can u please edit and send the same code..m not getting it..

Comment: Added an answer. Easy thing to overlook =D

Comment: See my answer. Give it a try.

Comment: Did it work for you?

Comment: What is the error exactly?

Comment: as i have input companyName,class,subject only...but it is asking for compnyUrl also

Comment: Please add the exact error to the question. Formatted if you can.

Comment: You need to share more code. Show the url and the view.

Comment: And in the traceback do you see where it originated?

Comment: And how does your `urls.py` look?

Comment: ?? @The_Cthulhu_Kid

Comment: I still can't see the exception. I need to see the exact error.

Answer (score 0):

Try and change the order of your `elif`s:

```
# This has to go first. If two of the conditions are fulfilled this will never be reached
elif (Q("CompanyUrl" in request) & Q("Subject" in request) & Q("Class" in request)):
  queryset = Product.objects.filter(Q(CompanyUrl=request['CompanyUrl']) | Q(Subject=request['Subject']) | Q(Class=request['Class']))

elif (Q("CompanyUrl" in request) & Q("Subject" in request)):
  queryset = Product.objects.filter(Q(CompanyUrl=request['CompanyUrl']) | Q(Subject=request['Subject']))

elif (Q("CompanyUrl" in request) & Q("Class" in request)):
  queryset = Product.objects.filter(Q(CompanyUrl=request['CompanyUrl']) | Q(Class=request['Class']))

elif (Q("Subject" in request) & Q("Class" in request)):
  queryset = Product.objects.filter(Q(Subject=request['Subject']) | Q(Class=request['Class']))
```